# Extract lines of text between delimiters and add them to a List<string>

Tags: c#, regex, list, parsing, text

I have a text file which contains some numbers between delimiters that I want to extract and add them to two different lists . The lists I want to populate are:

```
points = new List<string>();
coords = new List<string>();
```

This is how the input file looks like:

```
blah
blah
    point   [
         0 50 50,
         50 50 50,
         50 0 50,
         0 0 50,
        ]
blah
blah
coordIndex [
 3,2,0,-1,
 2,1,0,-1,
]
blah
blah

blah
blah
    point   [
         0 50 0,
         50 50 0,
         50 0 0,
         0 0 0,
        ]
blah
blah
coordIndex [
 3,0,2,-1,
 0,1,2,-1,
]
blah
blah
```

What I want to do is to get the numbers (including the commas) following the logic below:

1. Get the lines between the keywords "point    [" and the next "]". Each line is a "string".

   Add these lines to a the list "points"
2. Get the lines between the keywords "coordIndex [" and the next "]". Each line is a "string".

   Add these lines to a the list "coords"

So far I have only managed to get rid off the  blank spaces to "gain access" to the points field but I  do not know how to populate the lists.

Can someone help? I am happy to use regex or whatever other option.

The code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

namespace parsing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputFile = "Q:/inputFile.txt";

            //Lists to be populated
            var points = new List<string>();
            var coords = new List<string>();

            //Parsing the file
            using (StreamReader readInputFile = new StreamReader(inputFile))
            {

                string line;
                while ((line = readInputFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                    {
                        //Remove tabs
                        string line_noTabs = line.Replace("\t", "");

                        //Get lines between the keywords "point [" and the next "]". Each line is a "string".
                            //Add these lines to a the list "points"

                        //Get lines between the keywords "coordIndex [" and the next "]". Each line is a "string".
                            //Add these lines to a the list "coords"
                    }

                }
            }

        }//end main
    }//end program
}//end namespace
```

Comment: Bad way. I suggest you use regexp for this task http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match

Comment: Is this file actually JSON or does it just kinda look like it?

Answer (score 1):

You would just need to go through the file, one line at a time and set a series of flags which you can then later check to see in which chunk of your file you are.

You will then check with the flags to see to which list you will need to add your item.

Your code would need to look something like so:

```
using (StreamReader readInputFile = new StreamReader(inputFile))
{

    string line;
    bool isPoint = false;
    bool isCoord = false;
    Regex pointRegex = new Regex("point\\s+\\[");
    Regex coordRegex = new Regex("coordIndex\\s+\\[");
    Regex endBrace = new Regex("\\s*\\]\\s*");

    while ((line = readInputFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        {
            //Remove tabs
            string line_noTabs = line.Replace("\t", "");
            if(pointRegex.IsMatch(line_noTabs))
            {
                isPoint = true;
                continue;
            }
            else if(coordRegex.IsMatch(line_noTabs))
            {
                isCoord = true;
                continue;
            }
            else if (endBrace.IsMatch(line_noTabs))
            {
                isPoint = false;    //Reset
                isCoord = false;    //Reset
                continue;
            }

            if(isPoint)
                points.Add(line_noTabs);
            else if(isCoord)
                coords.Add(line_noTabs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very neat solution thank you. The only thing is that I would like each chunk of points and each chunk of coordinates in different lists. That is, foreach chunk of "points" I want to create a List<string> which could then be stored to another list called List<List<string>> allPoints which contains all the "chunks". Same logic for the coordinates. Do you know how this could be modified for this purpose? Sorry I wasn't accurate when I enunciated the question...

Comment: @user3641829: The current code places the entire line in the list, thus each line would be 1 element. Changing the collections ta List<string[]> and instread of addeing line_notab you add line_notab.splkt(',') should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

1. Use `\[([^\]]+)]` to get everything between the brackets (https://regex101.com/r/sG4zO1/1).
2. For each regex result, use `regexResult.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` to get an array of numbers inside the brackets.
3. Looping through the regex results, know:

   - if `index % 2 == 0`, then you are looking at `point` values
   - if `index % 2 == 1`, then you have `coordIndex` values

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get each line in each *point\coordIndex* batch as a new `Item` in a `List`, then by using a regex like `(\d+\s\d+\s\d+)|(\d,\d,\d,-?\d,)` you will get two groups of matches - one for points, and one for coordIndexes (this is relying on the examples you gave, if the data can vary then the regex will have to be improved).

If later on you need to use the numbers in those *point\coordIndex* strings, you will need to apply some c# to "parse" the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I change your list to integers.  I sued Regex but can easily change code to a method similar to your code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"C:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            string pattern = @"(?'type'\w+)\s+\[(?'array'[^\]]+)\]";
            Regex expr = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
            MatchCollection matches = expr.Matches(input);


            //Lists to be populated
            List<List<int>> points = new List<List<int>>();
            List<List<int>> coords = new List<List<int>>();


            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {

                string type = match.Groups["type"].Value;
                string strArray = match.Groups["array"].Value;
                StringReader reader = new StringReader(strArray);
                string line = "";
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    line = line.Trim();
                    if (line.Length > 0)
                    {
                        List<int> intArray = line.Split(new char[] { ',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
                        switch (type)
                        {
                            case "point":
                                points.Add(intArray);
                                break;
                            case "coordIndex":
                                coords.Add(intArray);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
​
```